# Getting an Exception thrown says "project.exe has triggerd a breakpoint" while trying to free an allocated memory of an array in C

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

I am trying to free helper. Everything is working ok except the free(helper).
This function is supposed to check if numbers are repeating. Can anyone help me find the problem?

```
int check_array(int *arr, int n) {
int i, max = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (arr[i] > max) max = arr[i];

int *helper = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * max);
if (!helper) return;
i = 0;
while (i < max) helper[i++] = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    helper[arr[i]]++;

for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    while (!helper[i]) i++;
    if (helper[i] > 1) {
        free(helper);
        return 0;
    }
}
free(helper);

return 1;}
```

In the main is just for the two examples.

```
void main() {
int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,100,120,130,140,150 };
int arr2[] = { 1,2,3,4,8,7,8,9,100,120,130,140,150 };
int size_arr = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
int size_arr2 = sizeof(arr2) / sizeof(arr2[0]);

printf("arr - %d\narr2 - %d\n", check_array(arr, size_arr), check_array(arr2, size_arr2));
}
```

Comment: just found my mistake.
the problem was that i allocated max instead of max + 1:
int *helper = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (max + 1);

i will leave that question anyway for others.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  (consider a closing brace '}' as a separate statement.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, 1) the returned value has type `void*`  so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: regarding: `if (!helper) return;`  when a C library function returns an error indication, a error message should be sent to `stderr` that includes your error text I.E. "malloc failed" and the text reason the system thinks the function failed.  the function: `perror()`; is made for that purpose

Comment: regarding: `void main()`  regardless of what visual studio might allow, all valid signatures for `main()` have a return type of `int`  Suggest  using: `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding: `if (!helper) return;`  the function `check_array()` has a signature that indicates the return type is an `int`.  So any and all exits from that function must return a value.

Comment: the posted code is not complete, so does not cleanly compile  Amongst other things, the posted code is missing the needed `#include` statement(s).  Are you expecting us the 'guess' as to what your 'real' code actually includes?

Comment: The call to 'malloc()' has an invalid parameter.  All parts of that parameter are expected to be of `size_t`  which (on most systems) is an unsigned long. however, the part of the parameter `max` is an `int` (a signed value)

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` Note: Other compilers use different compile options for the same effects.

Comment: You can avoid having to code a loop to set all the values in array `helper[]` to zero by calling `calloc()` rather than `malloc()`

Comment: the last `for()` can be greatly simplified by arranging any 'early out' by checking if the `helper[i]` is already > 0 before incrementing again. and if already >0 then `free()` and `return 0` .  Then no need to go through all the `helper[]` values again.

Comment: BTW: if your using a modern compiler, which has the `VLA` (Variable Length Array)  feature then you can calculate the number of entries in the array then use: `int helper[ max+1 ] = {0};` and not have to use `malloc()/calloc()` nor `free()`

Comment: BTW:  although the feature of being able to skip writing the 'optional' braces, when the body of a `while()` or `for()` only contains a single statement,  It is VERY easy, especially during debug or later maintenance to add some code that requires the braces, but you miss that fact.  I.E. skipping the optional braces makes it very likely that the final code will not be correct

Comment: @user3629249
I received very specific instructions for this exercise.

Comment: Please post those criteria, as part of your question, so we will know in what ways your hands are tied in the logic, sequence, etc of your code

Comment: hi, sorry for the delay @user3629249.
we needed to create a function that receives an array, find the maximum and check if one of the numbers returns itself in the array.
there is a "hint" that suggest you to fund the maximum number at first and the next followed by that hint.

Comment: and every number in the array is positive btw.

Answer (score 2):

You allocate space for `max` integers when you call

```
int *helper = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * max);
```

So you can only index `helper` from 0 to `max-1`.

Then later you increment: `helper[arr[i]]++;`. But note that at least one value of `arr[i]` is equal to `max`. Therefore you index out of bounds and write to memory that you don't own. This invokes undefined behavior which manifests in a crash later invoking `free`.